# uninitialized constant ActionController::Caching::Sweeping (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller

its an api based application

using rails 4.1.13

gem 'rails-observers'

app/config/initializers/base_sweeper.rb

```
class BaseSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe ActiveRecord::Base

  def after_save(object)
    # ..... call to version class for record saving purpose
  end

end
```

application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/services #{config.root}/lib)
```

app/services/version.rb

```
class Version
  #some method to store records
end
```

ChannelController.rb

```
classs Api::V1::ChannelsController < Api::V1::BaseController
 cache sweeper :base_sweeper, only: [:create, :update]
end

#channel.rb
has_many :channel_logs

#channel_log.rb
belongs_to :channel

development.rb
config.active_record.observers = :base_sweeper
```

I got an error uninitialized constant basesweeper?

Comment: any one know how to do these?